# Why getline does not work in a switch, and cin does not take the data appropriately?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I need to take in the make model and years of the car the particular product fits. The program is going to write a file with text in it that will be an outline of the html. I need with the crucial information inserted into the correct spots to quickly be able to add products to our web page. When I use a switch statement or if statements to separate the categories of the products, the input gets messed up and does not let me answer one of the questions. I can't just use cin because I need to take dates that look like "2008 - 2009 - 2010 - 2011".

Here is what I've got so far! This one is just regular `cin`, I have tried `getline` you could quickly c I started yesterday and I'm pretty new so forgive me if this is an easy fix, but I cant find anything.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void proinfo();

int main()
{
    //Sytem Information
    system("TITLE This is a Beta of My Product Information Template Version 0.0.2");

    //I'm using this as a welcome screen to inform users of new improvements on patches and other pertinent information to the users
    cout << "Welcome To My Product Information Template Maker!!! \n It Is Still In Development" << endl;
    cout << "\n\nworking features are:" << endl << "\t-None\n" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    system("CLS");
    proinfo();
}

void proinfo()
{
    //Declare Variables here
    int loop(1), protype;
    char make[256], model[256], year[256];
    string getinput;

    while(loop==1)
    {
        //This is the first menu the user sees where they have to choose what type 
        //of products users will be adding
        system("CLS");
        cout << "Welcome to My Product Information Template Version 0.0.0" << endl;

        cout << "Please select the number of the product" << endl;
        cout << "type you will be ading!\n" << endl;

        cout << "1.Fe - Fe2 Moldings" << endl;
        cout << "2.CF - CF2 Moldings" << endl;

        cout << "What would you like to do? ";

        cin >> protype;

        if(protype==1)
        {
            //FE - FE2 Molding
            system("cls");

            cout << "You have selected" << endl;
            cout << "Fe - Fe2 Moldings\n" << endl;

            cout << "Please Enter the Make of the molding" << endl;
            cin >> make;

            cout << "Please Enter the Model of the molding" << endl;
            cin >> model;

            cout << "Please Enter the Years this molding fits" << endl;
            cin >> year;

            cout << "You have just created a template for a(n)" << year << " " << make << " " << model << endl;
            cout << "Check My Documents For a file called Fe-Fe2template.txt" << endl;

            //Asks to quit or restart
            cout << "Would you like to make another tempalte?" << endl;

            cin >> getinput;

            if(getinput=="yes")
            {
                cout << "Great, Lets keep working!" << endl;
                //End of If statement
            }

            system("PAUSE");
        }

        if(protype==2)  
        {
            //CF - CF2 Molding
            system("cls");

            //Asks to quit or restart
            cout << "Would you like to make another tempalte?" << endl;

            cin >> getinput;

            if(getinput=="yes")
            {
                cout << "Great, Lets keep working!" << endl;
                //End of If statement                   
            }

            system("PAUSE");

            //End of Protype Switch Statement               
        }

        //End of while loop              
    }
    //End of Proinfo()    
}
```

Comment: So what is your question exactly?  What is the program doing that is different from what you want it to do?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and what is the possible output/behaviour you are expecting? Also your program would enter the infinite loop, you do not have any proper exit from the `while(1)` loop.

Comment: Drop DevC++ - it is no longer being developed, and many would say it should never have been developed in the first place. Switch to Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change year[256] to string year;

Change cin >> year; to getline(cin, year);

Add the line  cin.ignore(); before the getline.

Your main problem is that the stream operator >> leaves the newline in the stream so when you try to use getline it reads an empty line.  ignore() will chew up the newline and let you read the string you expect.

So this should get you on your way.

```
cin.ignore();
cout << "Please Enter the Years this molding fits" << endl;
getline(cin, year);
```

You have some other small problems but you'll figure them out.  The worst is forgetting to terminate the loop.

```
if(getinput=="yes")
{
    cout << "Great, Lets keep working!" << endl;
   //End of If statement
}
else
{
    loop = 0;
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I'm going to give this a shot. I'm sorry to ask this if it's stupid but why do you have to terminate the loop? Normally I would I just always choose yes while experimenting, and then exit with the x, so I did not see the need. Am I causing memory leaks doing it this way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by exit with x - kill the terminal window?

Comment: Yeah I don't know the technical term I just use the x in the top right of the window.

Comment: Yes, that's not the way to properly end a program.  It sends a signal to kill your pgm and unless you handle it properly it won't save data, etc., in an orderly way.  Put an exit into the loop and do it correctly.